# Error when converting a single str character to integer and it saves in a list

Tags: python, list, minesweeper

Here is the code that causes the error in coordinate init:

```
self.estate = "x"

def set_estate(self, estate):
    self.estate = estate

    self.table[coordinate_line][coordinate_column].set_estate("!")
```

I get this error:

```
list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: Welcome the StackOverflow. Please properly indent your code and format your question, providing the full error trace as well as parts of your missing code.

Comment: print `coordinate_line` and `coordinate_column`, check that they are both integers

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your code and your question are not clear. Please read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure your code is self-contained and can run (or start to run) as shown. Show the entire traceback that comes from that code.

Comment: yes they correspond at what i choose

Answer (score 0):

This exception occurs when you try to access a value in a list using something other than an integer or slice. This would mean that the data type of either `coordinate_line` or `coordinate_column` is not an integer or slice. This works with values you can convert to an `int`:

```
self.table[int(coordinate_line)][int(coordinate_column)].set_estate("!")
```

Comment: Thanks now it works! I thought it was the other thing nevermind!